# How to create style of DataGridCell based on IsReadOnly?

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to create a style for DataGrid in Silverlight that shows Background color based on its IsReadOnly property. My situation is I have a DataGrid with four columns, column one and two are readonly, column three and four are not readonly (not set this property or set it to false.)

I tried to add   but it didn't work. I want to know, how can I do this in Silverlight 5?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the Background of your CellTemplate and use a converter to convert boolean value to a Color as per your choice.

To learn about converter refer
http://www.exploresilverlight.com/2012/06/converter-in-silverlight.html

Cheers!
Vinod